# When new window opens, i would like to previous one to close, so only 1 window is active at all times

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

I am working on a project for work, and although I studied this in school, I am still fairly new to programming.

I have my different windows in a def and when I click a button which is "next step", they next def opens up with the next window. However, I cant figure out how to make the previous window close automatically once the new window opens.

There is part of the code where when I press button "91ERP00500CAA", the next window "def caa1" opens, however the first window does not close.

```py
class Window:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = root
        root.title("Housing specification")
        master.geometry("1900x1080") #set the size of the screen
        
        #Frame
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.frame.pack()
        
        #Label , welcome to spec
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame, text = "Housing specification")
        self.label.place(x = 10, y = 10)
        
        self.buttoncaa = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "91ERP00500CAA", command = self.caa1)
        self.buttoncaa.place(x = 30, y = 80)
        
        def quit_win():
            win.quit()
   
        
        
       
    #Reference test for CAA specification
    def caa1(self):
        top = Toplevel()
        top.title("91ERP00500CAA - REFERENCE TEST")
        top.geometry("1900x1080")
        reference = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\rnorris\Desktop\3.10.PNG")
        ref = Label(top, image = reference)
        ref.pack()
        
        
        
        self.ns1 = tk.Button(top, text="Next step", command = self.caa2)
        self.ns1.pack()
        
        self.permit1 = tk.Button(top, text="Permits", command = self.permitref)
        self.permit1.pack()
        mainloop()
```

I have tried using `root.destroy()`, however no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier to help, please provide a [mre] which shows how you use `Window`. Please also explain how `root.destroy()` didn't work.

Comment: Hi, so I have removed away the code so that I have just the bare minimum for what I would like to achieve. So I have "Window" is the object which displays the images in the program (Hopefully that makes sense, I am a visual person so explaining over a forum is hard for me!). when  the "self.buttoncaa = tk.Button(self.frame, text = "91ERP00500CAA", command = self.caa1)"  button is pressed, it displays another window OVER THE TOP of the original window, and this is the same as when root.destroy() is used. Hopefully, this makes sense

Comment: This question still need clarification.  Do you actually want to `destroy` the window or just hide it with something like `withdraw`?  What do you expect your `quit_win` method to do there is nothing bound to `win` from what I can see?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you initialise `Window` with something like

```
root = tk.Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

you'll need to change your `__init__` to

```
def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Housing specification")
        self.master.geometry("1900x1080") #set the size of the screen
```

because at the moment it uses a mixture of `root`, `master` and `self.master` when it should just use `self.master`.

To destroy the window when the button is pressed, change `caa1` to

```
def caa1(self):
    self.master.destroy()
    top = tk.Tk()
    top.title("91ERP00500CAA - REFERENCE TEST")
    top.geometry("1900x1080")
    self.reference = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\rnorris\Desktop\3.10.PNG")
    ref = tk.Label(top, image = self.reference)
    ref.pack()
```

This will destroy the first window and create a new one. I've changed `Toplevel` to `Tk` because otherwise an extra empty window would be created when the original one is destroyed. There should only ever be one instance of `Tk` at a time, but you're destroying the previous instance before creating the next one so it's not a problem.

Also note that because `reference` is local to `caa1`, it will get garbage collected. I've changed it to `self.reference` so it doesn't get garbage collected and the image will show.

Whilst the above should work, consider using a single window which subclasses `Tk` and changing frames, something like

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Housing specification")
        self.geometry("1900x1080") #set the size of the screen

        self.frame_1 = tk.Frame(self, width = 200, height = 200)
        self.frame_1.pack()

        #Label , welcome to spec
        self.label = tk.Label(self.frame_1, text = "Housing specification")
        self.label.place(x = 10, y = 10)
        
        self.buttoncaa = tk.Button(self.frame_1, text = "91ERP00500CAA", command = self.caa1)
        self.buttoncaa.place(x = 30, y = 80)

    def caa1(self):
        self.frame_1.pack_forget()
        self.title("91ERP00500CAA - REFERENCE TEST")
        self.reference = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\rnorris\Desktop\3.10.PNG")
        self.frame_2 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame_2.pack()
        self.ref = tk.Label(self.frame_2, image = self.reference)
        self.ref.pack()

app = Window()
app.mainloop()
```

This is simpler to extend and nicer to use.